# Constructing an object without assigning it in Visual Basic.NET

Tags: vb.net

I've used VB.net for several years now, but keep coming across little quirks that I don't know how to work around.  Curiosity finally got the best of me, so I ask now:  **is there a way to create an object without assigning it?**

For example, say I have an Engine class, that I want to instantiate and have it immediately do whatever it needs to do.  If there's nothing I need to do with Engine after creating it, I have, till now, done something like:

**dim myEngine as new Engine()**

Is there a way to avoid the "dim myEngine as" part?  You certainly can in Java.  I could just create an object with "**new Engine()**" in java and not assign it to anything.

Why do I need this?  Because often I want to create a delegate object (hence I called it "engine") that performs some functionality, but otherwise I don't need to ever reference it.  I used to have such objects have a "public sub perform", but have found that cumbersome -- I'd rather just create the object and not worry about remembering to call its perform method.  And I find it aesthetically displeasing to create references to objects that I don't intend to use.

Any VB guru have a suggestion?

Thanks,

-- Michael

Comment: Maybe a Static method would solve your problem? Instead of declaring a new object.

Comment: A static would not be the solution, either:  my engine might want to have its own private fields/variables.  What I want is exactly what I get with the "dim myEngine as new Engine()", except I'm surprised to find I need the dim...

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish here? This is another one of those questions that asks how to accomplish the crazy hack/workaround you've envisioned, rather than simply asking what the *right* way is to accomplish your ultimate goal. This is *wrong* in Java, too. What the heck does that object **do** after you've created it? Lives and dies? That's a pointless existence, philosophical implications notwithstanding. It's not only aesthetically displeasing to "create references to objects you don't intend to use", it's completely nonsensical. Don't create the object in the first place.

Comment: Hi CodeGray, please see my detailed response below (it was too length for a comment)

Answer (score 6):

To do this you need to put the New declaration inside Parentheses ( )

you can try this syntax:

```
Call New TheClass().Method1()
```

or:

```
DoSomething(New TheClass())
```

or even:

```
DoSomething(New TheClass().GetStringData())
```

Source: http://tutorials.beginners.co.uk/vb-net-programming-part-6-interacting-with-objects.htm

Comment: Hi Tony, thanks for your quick response.  I'm not sure if that answers my question thought.  In my case I want **neither** to **DoSomething** nor call a method.  I just want to declare an object, and let it live its life (and then get collected by the garbage collector at some point, I suppose).  Makes sense?  Any thoughts on how to achieve that?

Comment: No, doesn't make sense.  It could be collected a microsecond later.

Comment: No, it would not.  The garbage collector does not act immediately upon an object going out of scope.  More information about the non-deterministic basis of the .net garbage collector can be found at:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee787088.aspx

Comment: @Brian: That's an implementation detail. *Theoretically*, it could be collected a mere microsecond later. The point is this requirement doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @michael-zlatkovsky I wrote another answer based on your new explanations of the requirement.

Comment: Hi Tony, please see my detailed response below (it was too length for a comment)

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps the issue is your design choice of the constructor performing real work, instead of putting that real work in methods?  The constructor is meant to build the object's state from one or more set of parameters.  Methods perform actions.

A static class can indeed have its own private methods and fields.  Not instances of them, sure, but for a single "instance" that would work fine.

Could you go into a bit more detail about the whys of this design choice/methodology, and perhaps we can offer some insight in how to design your objects more effectively.

Alternatively, you can anonymously create an object and call a method by:

```
Call New obj().method()
```

Comment: I made a correction on my answer using your information about using the Call keyword. Thank you!

Comment: Hi Brian, please see my detailed response below (it was too lengthy for a comment)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your answers, everybody.  It seems like few of you agree with my particular design choice, which is fine, and I'd love to hear how you would go about this problem.  But first let me explain why I'm doing what I'm doing.

Suppose I have a class, Exporter, dedicated to exporting a file.  It is a class, not a module, because I might want to have several exporters each with their own settings, etc.  So now I have

**dim myExporter as new Exporter()**

My exporter needs to have some data given to it, and a filename to save into.  So I now have several options:

1)  keep the empty exporter constructor and add
**myExporter.performExport(data, filename)**

I don't particularly like this, if the exporter is complicated (and my premise is that it is -- otherwise a module would have done fine), then I want it to maintain its own state, which just might be related to the data and filename.  It makes more sense to redo the constructor, as in option #2:

2)  pass the parameters in the constructor:

**dim myExporter as new Exporter(data, filename)**

and then call with a simple no-argument call:
myExporter.performExport()

This is fine, but notice how essentially, even though I'm declaring myExporter, I am only using it as a one-shot call:  create and perform export.  Essentially I *don't* need a reference to it, as @brian-m suggested, I could just do

**Call new Exporter(data, filename).performExport()**

(@code-gray, note how I now am using an object without a reference, yet it's not non-sensical).

But now I just have to type extra code every time -- the performExport() part.  If I know I will always want to act upon the object as soon as it's created (@brian-m, I agree that there *are* some cases when I might want to prepare my object and then DELAY execution, but at other times the execution may as well happen immediately after object creation) I may as well put the acting code in the constructor too, so I don't worry about forgetting to make the call.  So now I have

**dim myExporter as new Exporter(data, filename)**

which needs no further call, because it exports immediately upon being created.  From the rest of the program's perspective, I don't care what happens to the exporter once it's done -- I did not mean to get hung up on garbage collection, I just wanted to say that I have no need in maintaining a reference to the exporter.

So far so good?  If so, then I hope you'll agree with me that it would make even more sense to get rid of the "dim myExporter as" part, and just leave "**new Exporter(data, filename)**".  Except VB.NET, unlike Java, does not seem to allow that.

Thanks for reading, I'm looking forward to hearing your suggestions.

-- Michael

Comment: I don´t know if this is possible in VB.Net (I was not able to use this syntax). I tried to do in C# and it worked. Maybe you can use C# to do this.

Comment: You can suggest this to Microsoft. Maybe they can make an analysis and add this feature to the VB.Net language.  http://connect.microsoft.com

Comment: This won't ever get added to the language. You can suggest until you're blue in the fingers. Sounds like you need to read a book about object-oriented programming. How in the *world* do you stand working with the .NET Framework? This isn't how it works, certainly. It doesn't make *any sense at all* for an object to retain state information in private variables if you don't maintain a reference to it or ever use it again. What you're describing is what's known as "calling a static method". It *still* isn't clear from your description why you find this inadequate.

Comment: Try not to think of the constructor as an actionable method; by design and definition, it is not.  It is meant solely for building the initial state of an object, and not for performing methods.  Given that the state of this object needs to be maintained for only one method call, a shared/static method would likely be the route to go (keeping in mind this is not thread safe and such like that)

Comment: Not suggesting this.  But technically it solves one of your problems with the "call" technique (you ToString doesn't provide value other than to make it compile.  You won't forget to call it because it won't compile otherwise.):
Call new Exporter(data, filename).ToString()

Comment: Would a Singleton pattern fulfill this requirement (using Lazy<T>)?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can declare your global object in a Module...

```
Module GlobalModule
    Public x As Double = 110
    Public myObject As AutonomousObject = New AutonomousObject()    ' This will instantiate the object
End Module
```

... create a Class ...

```
Public Class AutonomousObject
    Public Sub New()
        MessageBox.Show("Hello, I was instantiated now. " + System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name)
    End Sub

    Public Sub Start()
        MessageBox.Show("Hello, I am initialized! " + System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name)
    End Sub
End Class
```

... and then use it from anywhere, without need to instantiate it again

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    MessageBox.Show(GlobalModule.x)    ' Will display 110
    ' OR
    GlobalModule.myObject.Start()    ' This will call a method that will display a message
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

There are times when an object's constructor will "connect" the object to another object passed as a parameter, and the code which calls the constructor will have no further use for the object reference.  I would suggest that "New" calls which ignore the result should not be used outside the class, but instead the class should provide a wrapper method something like:

```
  Sub AddNewItemToList(TheList as MyListType, TheData as DataToGoInNewItem)
    GC.KeepAlive(New MyListNode(TheList, TheData))
  End Sub
```

The GC.KeepAlive method could really be called "GC.PretendToUseTheParameterButDontActuallyDoAnythingWithIt", which would be precisely the semantics you're looking for here.

Comment: Why keep the object from being garbage collected if you *never plan on using it again?* If you *did* plan on using it again, you would instantiate it and assign a reference to it to a local variable. Which is precisely what the asker *doesn't* want.

Comment: @Cody Gray: The object will be used again, but not in the context where it was created.  As a simple example, a UI control which is tightly bound to its parent might accept a parent control as an argument to its constructor argument, and constructing it might cause it to be joined to the parent and displayed.  The new control would hardly be useless, but that doesn't mean it would ever again be needed by the routine that created it.

Comment: Where are you reading that from the original question? I don't see anything about UI controls or parent controls. It says "is there a way to create an object without assigning it?" If you assign the object to a list or a UI control, you're assigning it.

Comment: @Cody Gray: I was assuming that the constructor would have a useful side-effect even if the value was ignored; otherwise it would be useless to run it at all.  The most common type of useful side-effect for a constructor is to attach the new object into some other data structure.  My interpretation of the question was how to run the constructor so as to achieve its side-effects, while ignoring the return value.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand this correctly then you are trying to avoid the memory that would be used up by the object that you are instantiating even when you don't want to use it. 
If that's the case then why not use Singleton Object. Which is instantiated only once and first time when you call it.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a dummy method on your class and use the aforementioned solution with the Call keyword

```
Call (New Engine()).dummy()
```

To spice things up you can probably create a dummy extension method on any of your existing classes

Or you can use reflection to one line the code without modifying anything

```
GetType(Engine).GetConstructor(types:= New Type(){} ).Invoke(parameters:= New Object(){})
```

Btw, you can add me to the list of people not agreeing with your design choice of doing significant work in the constructor.