# How to refresh a combo box list that is reading from a txt file

Tags: vb.net

How do I get the latest info from a .txt file that is linked to my combo box? I have a form that writes to a .txt file, and another form (combo box) that reads from that .txt file. But the form that reads doesn’t get the latest inputs to the .txt file unless I close the form and reopen it. How can I tell the combobox to refresh the .txt file?
[image: Screen Shot]

```
    Private Sub RadioButton1_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RadioButton1.CheckedChanged
    If RadioButton1.Checked = True Then
        Dim FILE_NAME As String = "C:\Users\ladam\Desktop\Fiber Type.txt"
        ComboBox1.Items.Clear()


        If IO.File.Exists(FILE_NAME) Then
            Using sr As New IO.StreamReader(FILE_NAME)
                While Not sr.EndOfStream

                    ComboBox1.Items.Add(sr.ReadLine)
                End While
            End Using
        Else

            MsgBox("Oooops, File not found !!!")
        End If
        Label8.Text = "fl oz"
        Label23.Text = "(sq in)"
        Label24.Text = "(sq in)"
```

Comment: **Hint:** [BindingList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.bindinglist-1?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: Is that something that works with a .txt file? I’m trying to find more info about it, but most searches are showing  examples in C#

Comment: You have to paste the relevant code to help us understand your logic. How do write/read to and from the txt? file How do you populate the ComboBox? Maybe a screenshot? and you'll get many answers.  You won't get something useful from guessing.

Comment: Okay, I updated my question. The form on the left saves to the .txt file, then it's closed.  The form in the middle has a combobox linked to that .txt file, but when you click the dropdown it doesn't show what you just added to the .txt file. You have to close the center form and reopen it to get the added data to show in the combobox.

Answer (score 1):

Dare say your life would be a lot easier I you used a DataSet and a bunch of datatables and bound all these combos to them:

I would do the following. The steps I describe here should take about 5 minutes to complete, with a few extra minute to replicate various bits of code:

- Right click your project in Solution Explorer
- Choose Add New...
- Choose DataSet (under Data) pick a name
- If it doesn't open automatically, double click it. You see an empty design surface
- Right click the surface, Add New.. DataTable
- Call it Fiber
- Right click it, Add.. Column, Call it FiberThickness, use the properties grid to give it a suitable datatype (double?)
- Add a column for FiberWeight
- Add another *datatable* and *columns* for Veil (you can see this is starting to look like a mini database)
- Keep going adding a datatable and then columns for all the related properties. I guess at the end you will have 7 datatables and all but the last will have 2 columns
- Save the dataset design
- Open the designer for the DB form (without the red and blue button)
- Open the Data Sources window, on the View menu inside Other Windows
- Expand the dataset's node in the DataSources window and drag one of the tables onto the form - a grdiview will be created, along with a dataset (at the bottom in a tray), bindingsource and a binding navigator. Delete the the navigator, leaving just the grid, dataset and the bindingsource
- Rename the dataset in the bottom tray; click on it and change the name in the properties grid so it has a leading underscore. This helps because things can get confusing in VB when variables have the same name as the Type of object, and in this case the form designer did a  a `Dim thermoLamDataSet as New ThermoLamDataSet` - the two names differ only by case and VB isn't case sensitive so adding a leading underscore helps keep things separate and know if we're talking about a variable or a type
- Repeat the process of adding, then deleting. At the end you should have one dataset and 7 bindingsources in the tray, and 7 grids on the form. Arrange the grids nicely because they are going to take the place of your textboxes (your "database" will know of multiple Fibers/Veils etc; using a textbox to show them isn't ideal because it can only show one thing at once - grids work better for this, cos your users can scroll up and down the entries and edit them, delete them and add more of them)
- If you're absolutely wedded to the idea of keeping the *textboxes*, then follow this process instead:

  - Expand the Fiber node in the datasources window, see how the columns are now listed? Drag each column onto the form. Again you get a dataset, bindingnav, bindingsource in your tray but this time you get textboxes
  - These textboxes you just dropped are already connected (bound) to the dataset's table columns. Delete your old text boxes and arrange the new ones nicely. Put the bindingnavigator suitably near the textboxes in the panel too. It will be used to change what the textboxes show so the user can scroll through the records in the fiber table and edit existing ones, delete them, add new etc
- Now we have a form that is capable of editing every row in the datables of the dataset. Add a Save button (and maybe a SaveAs.. and a Load button) or put some code to save the dataset when the form is closed:

```
    Sub Form_Closing(...)
      _myDataSet.WriteXml(Path.ChangeExtension(Application.ExecutablePath, "xml"))

    End Sub
```

This one line of code will save the whole dataset and the contents of every table to a path that is the same as the exe name, but with an xml extension. You can provide a different logic if you want. *It's not essential* for the communication to the other form to work, it's just that I guess you don't want your user to have to enter all this data every time they open the app...

---

The next thing we need to do is make it so that this form can take the dataset as a parameter when it is created. This is so that the main form can be the one responsible for creating the dataset, but it will pass its dataset to this form for editing. This is how the two forms will share the same data, and edits made on this form will be reflected on the main form

Put a constructor:

```
Public Sub New(ds as ThermoLamDataSet) 'whatever you called your dataset,

    _thermoLamDataSet = ds 'remember I said to change the name of the dataset in the tray at the bottom of the form - here _thermoLamDataSet is whateve the dataset in the tray is called

End Sub
```

In the main form when the user clicks the (Edit DataBase?) button we will pass the instance of the main form's dataset to this form when we are editing:

```
Public Sub EditDatabaseButton_Click(...) Handles EditDbButton.Click

  Call New EditorForm(Me._tlDS).Show() 'I'm going to rename the dataset on this form to _tlDS below

End Sub
```

I've decided to call the dataset on the main form `_tlDS` to highlight that it's different to the one on the editor form. It's the same *type* of dataset though, so the one from the main form can be passed to the editor form, used and the communication thus happens; both forms are using the same object in memory, they just have different names for it. The could have the same names, I just didn't want you to assume they *had* to have the same names

Let's set up the main form:

- Open the main form designer
- Open the data sources window
- Expand the dataset node name, and the Fiber node. Use the dropdown next to the FiberThickness column to change from a textbox to a combobox.
- Drag the FiberThickness combo onto the form, again a bunch of stuff appears in the tray. If a navigator appears, delete it - we don't need it. Change the dropdownstyle of the combo to be DropDownList
- Rename the dataset in the tray at the bottom of the forms designer, change its name to `_tlDS` or similar (i picked this because I assumed a name of ThermoLamDataSet was chosen when adding the dataset file to the project). I usually also rename by bindingsources etc so they all have a leading underscore. I do this with my buttons etc.. everything gets a leading undersore if it's a class level variable, in my apps and buttons and labels all get sensible names (never button12, label26...)
- Repeat for the other tables in the data sources window (veil...)

You now have a main form with a dataset, a bunch of bindingsources, and some comboboxes that are bound to the dataset's tables via those bindingsources.

You can run the project at this point, Click the Edit DB button..

- If you kept textboxes, hit the + in the bindingnavigator and write some data in the textboxes, click + again, add some more etc. You can scroll the added records.
- If you picked to use a grid, it's a bit more intuitive; write new records in the bottom row, edit editing records like you would an excel sheet

Close the form, and look in the main form combos; the data you edited / added is there, because both forms work off the same dataset (the one created by the main form).

The other bits we need to do:

- Add a routine to load the dataset when the app launches
- Add some convenience properties to get the current row of each datatable. I presume you'll need this because after the user picks a Thickness you'll want to know the associated weight so you can calculate something

Adding a routine to load the dataset:

```
Public Sub MainFormLoad(...) Handles MainForm.Load


  Dim path = Path.ChangeExtension(Application.ExecutablePath, "xml")
  If File.Exists(path) Then _myDataSet.ReadXml()

End Sub
```

Yep, just one line will read the dataset from the same location the other form saved it to (if you adjusted this logic, make the same adjustment here)

And a convenience property that gets the whole Fiber row related to whatever the user picked in the fiber combo:

```
ReadOnly Property CurrentFiberRow() As ThermoLamDataSet.FiberRow
    Get
      'do'nt forget, I rename my BindingSources from the default fiberBindingSource to _fiberBindingSource
      If _fiberBindingSource.Current Is Nothing Then Return Nothing
      Return DirectCast(DirectCast(_fiberBindingSource.Current, DataRowView).Row, ThermoLamDataSet.FiberRow)
    End Get
```

We would use it like this, maybe (I don't know what your calc is):

```
If CurrentFiberRow Is Nothing Then
  MessageBox.Show("Choose a fiber thickness first!")
  Return
End If

Dim result = CurrentFiberRow.Thickness * CurrentFiberRow.Weight * Convert.ToDouble(fiberAreaTextBox.Text)

...
```

Comment: Well this gives me something to look into. The screen shots on that link don't look the same as my system, its from 9 years ago, But I think I can research it more though. My only goal is to let the user add to the comboboxs, and customize there selections for future sessions. Would a DataSet and DataTable do this also? I am fairly new to this coding stuff so I don't know what is possible, and how to find it. Thanks for pointing me in a new direction.

Comment: I took the link out again because more fudging would be required than I had time to explain- one cannot bind to a List(Of String) because binding requires a property and the only property on a string is Length. I'll put some words about a DataSet..

Comment: Caius, thanks for taking the time to help me with this!  I have been working my way down your instructions here, and the first question I have is how to save the Dataset. Do I need to change _myDataSet.WriteXml... to what I named my DataSet _DataSet1?

Comment: I'm getting a "Path not declared" error at this section of your code. "(Path.ChangeExtension" on the save code you posted, and also the (...) show an error. Do I need to change those to something?

Comment: Yes.. `...` is my placeholder for something else; I post mostly from a cellphone and I don't always remember the exact number and types of arguments in event handlers etc, so where you see `Sub Form_Closing(...)` this is the Form Closing event handler. The best way to create such an event handler is to open the designer, click on the background part of the form so it is the form that is selected, then go to the Events tab of the properties grid and double click in Form Closing. The designer will add the method for you that handles the form closing event, you just put the code into it

Comment: I don't know exactly all the variable names etc that you've used so there will still be a bit of work to change the code provided so it suits your purpose. If you're getting an error about `Path` not being available, you probably need to `Imports System.IO` at the top of your code (where the other Imports are), or change it to `System.IO.Path.ChangeExtension(...)`

Comment: Thanks for being patient with me on this, and helping me understand how to navigate this process. I'm making some good progress now. I'm at the EditDatabase button section now, and I'm getting an error at "New" I put the "constructor" code on the Edit Database form and replaced what you had, with the names I created. No errors there. But on the main form I'm getting the syntax error at "New". Did I add them on the correct forms?

  New EditorForm(Me._tlDS).Show()

Comment: Ty swapping it out for `Dim x as New EditorForm(Me._tlds)` then `x.Show()` - I might be assuming incorrectly that what works in c# works in vb!

Comment: Oh.. turns out you can prefix it with `Call` if you want to use New without Dim - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4964424/constructing-an-object-without-assigning-it-in-visual-basic-net

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213520/discussion-between-malachilee-and-caius-jard).

Answer (score 1):

Move the code to fill the combobox to a separate `Sub`. This is then called from the `RadioButton1_CheckedChanged` event. I changed the code a bit to simplify it. `.ReadAllLines` returns an array of lines in the text file. Then `.AddRange` adds the array to the combo.

Set the visibility to `Friend` so it can be called from other Forms.

Form1 code

```
Private Sub RadioButton1_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RadioButton1.CheckedChanged
    If RadioButton1.Checked = True Then
        FillCombo()
    End If
End Sub
Friend Sub FillCombo()
    Dim FILE_NAME As String = "C:\Users\ladam\Desktop\Fiber Type.txt"
    ComboBox1.Items.Clear()
    If File.Exists(FILE_NAME) Then
        Dim lines = File.ReadAllLines(FILE_NAME)
        ComboBox1.Items.AddRange(lines)
    Else
        MsgBox("Oooops, File not found !!!")
    End If
End Sub
```

Form2

```
Private Sub WriteToFile()
    'Code that writes to text file
    Form1.FillCombo()
End Sub
```

This will work if you are using the default instances of Forms. If you are creating your own instances (not default) `Form2` will need a reference to `Form1`.

Form1

```
Private Sub OpenForm2()
    Dim frm As New Form2
    frm.Show()
    frm.frm1 = Me
End Sub
```

Form2

```
Friend frm1 As Form1

Private Sub WriteToFile()
    'Code that writes to text file
    frm1.FillCombo()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Extending the [BindingList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.bindinglist-1?view=netcore-3.1) suggestion. I believe the Form on the right side which hosts the ComboBox is the main Form so I'm answering accordingly.

**MainForm**

---

- Declare a class variable of BindingList type.
- Create a new instance in the constructor and load the data from the text file.
- Bind the ComboBox.
- Handle the FormClosing event to update the text file.

```vb
Imports System.ComponentModel
'...

Public Class MainForm

    Private ReadOnly FiberType As BindingList(Of String)

    Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()

        Dim filePath = "C:\Users\ladam\Desktop\Fiber Type.txt"

        FiberType = New BindingList(Of String)(File.ReadAllLines(filePath).ToList)
        FiberType.AllowNew = True
        ComboBox1.DataSource = FiberType
    End Sub

    Private Sub MainForm_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
        File.WriteAllLines("C:\Users\ladam\Desktop\Fiber Type.txt", FiberType)
    End Sub

End Class
```

**The Data Entry Form**

---

- Create a parameterized constructor to pass the BindingList.
- Add the new entry to the BindingList.

```vb
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class FrmFiberType

    Private ReadOnly FiberType As BindingList(Of String)

    Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
    End Sub

    Sub New(data As BindingList(Of String))
        Me.New
        FiberType = data
    End Sub

    Private Sub BtnNewFiber_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnNewFiber.Click
        FiberType.Add("The new type...")
    End Sub

End Class
```

That's it. Anything you add in the data entry Form will show up in the ComboBox of the main Form.

Alternative to the parameterized constructor, you can declare the `FiberType` in a module to access the list anywhere in your project.

```vb
Module Module1
    Friend ReadOnly FiberType As BindingList(Of String)
End Module
```

Then instantiate a new instance in the main Form as mentioned, or in the [MyApplication_Startup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.applicationservices.windowsformsapplicationbase.startup?view=netframework-4.8) event.

Also you might want to read:

- [BindingList.AllowEdit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.bindinglist-1.allowedit?view=netcore-3.1#System_ComponentModel_BindingList_1_AllowEdit)
- [BindingList.AllowRemove](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.bindinglist-1.allowremove?view=netcore-3.1#System_ComponentModel_BindingList_1_AllowRemove)
- [BindingList.RaiseListChangedEvents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.bindinglist-1.raiselistchangedevents?view=netcore-3.1#System_ComponentModel_BindingList_1_RaiseListChangedEvents)